# Putnam, A3 (2016)

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math, improper-integrals

Let $f: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfying \begin{equation*} f(x) + f\bigg(1-{1\over x}\bigg) = \arctan x\end{equation*}
for all $x\neq 0$. I want to evaluate \begin{equation*} \int_0^1 f(x) dx \end{equation*}

I know that $\tan\bigg(f(x) + f\bigg(1-{\cfrac 1x}\bigg)\bigg) = x$ and $-\pi/2 < f(x) + f\bigg(1-{1\over x}\bigg) < \pi/2$, but none of this seems useful yet. Since $x\neq 0$, the answer should be the solution to
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\int_n^1f(x)dx\end{equation*}
But again, I'm still unsure where to go from here. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Try playing with $x$ in your initial equation.

Comment: @ericforman, I have, one of my results was $f(0) = \pi/4 + f(1)$

Comment: @ericforman Oh wait, hold up. $1-1/x > 0$ only when $x > 1$. But our domain is $(0, 1]$, so does that mean $f(1-1/x)$ is not defined on $(0, 1]$, so we treat it as zero?

Comment: Try to see how a substitution involving $x$ would help you get a more helpful expression. Seeing as the expression includes $\arctan x$ some substitutions should come to mind.

Comment: One possible hint: I recognize $1 - \frac{1}{x}$ as a rational function which gives the identity if you compose it with itself three times.